# What's the equivalent of C# TcpClient GetStream in nodejs?

Tags: c#, node.js, sockets

I'm trying to convert a C# socket connector to nodejs but I can't figure out how to read the stream from the socket. Basically I'm trying to convert this bit of code from C# to nodejs:

```
private TcpClient client = new TcpClient();    
client.Connect(host, port);
client.NoDelay = true;

this.NetworkStream = client.GetStream();
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: rtfm ? https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_connect_options_connectlistener

Comment: Did [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41211286/whats-the-equivalent-of-c-sharp-tcpclient-getstream-in-nodejs/41211588#41211588) help you?

Comment: yes it did, now I'm able to connect, thanks @rsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`net.connect()`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_connect_options_connectlistener) function returns a [`net.Socket`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket) instance, which is a stream, i.e. it implements a duplex [Stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) interface.

See:

- https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_connect_options_connectlistener
- https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket
- https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable
- https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_writable